# Convert MySQL dayofmonth query to db agnostic in Rails app

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Is there a way to create a database agnostic query that does the equivalent of this:

```
group by DAYOFMONTH(performed_on)
```

I need it to work in at least MySQL and Postgres. I'm using Rails/ActiveRecord so perhaps something there will help? Here's my code:

```
@works = Work.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :performed_on => (@date.beginning_of_month..@date.end_of_month))
...
@works.select('sum(hours) as total_hours, DAYOFMONTH(performed_on) as day').group('DAYOFMONTH(performed_on)')
```

Answer (score 3):

The notation `EXTRACT(DAY FROM ...)`, which I believe comes from the SQL standard, works [in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) and [in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract).

Comment: +1  Also Firebird, HyperSQL and Oracle.  Sadly not sqlite3, however.